# Google only indexing English content for multi-language website -- default not English

Tags: seo, multilingual, google-search

I have a multi-language website. The default language is German. Google seems to be indexing only the English version at `example.de/en/`. The redirect being used is based on geolocation. For example if someone visits the site from outside of Germany, they will see the `/en/` site.

From what I understand Google crawlers will end up redirecting because they are based in the USA and thus will only index the English version of the site both on google.com and google.de. Since my site is targeting primarily Germany, I want to make sure that when someone searches on google.de they will see the German site in the results. What is the best way for me to go about this? I am currently using the `hreflang` property. For example on the English site we have this code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://mysite.de/" />
```

And on the German site we have this code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://mysite.de/en/" />
```

Shouldn't Google recognize this and display relevant search results based on which version of Google is being queried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde where would it be on-topic? seems like a relevant question related to code as well.

Comment: [webmasters.se] would be appropriate. (It’s, by the way, also mentioned in the tag description of the [tag:seo] tag.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `hreflang` links properly. You need to use `x-default` for the default language and you need to add multiple `hreflang` links to specify alternate version of your pages, in each page. You could also achieve this by using `hreflang` in your sitemap. Check [here](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/internationalization-multi-language-seo-checklist.html) for more details.

Right now, Google is probably confused by what your are trying to achieve, because the information is incomplete. It probably tries to play it safe to avoid duplicate content.